# Wrong Number of Elements for reading from console with UFT

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have the following simple problem with UFT.

My Script is:

```
Dim testShell
Set testShell = CreateObject ("wscript.shell")
testShell.exec "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
msgbox(testShell.Exec.StdOut)
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Wrong number of Arguments : 'testShell.exec' Line (4): "msgbox(testShell.Exec.StdOut)".

I have looked at several VbScripts so far and there it seems to work with no problems. Why does my script fail? I am very sure it is something very stupid and simple, but i cannot see my error. I just want to get the output of my shell into a variable so i can work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the object returned by .Exec to get the .StdOut and its content and `/K` should be `/C`:

```
>> Set testShell = CreateObject ("wscript.shell")
>> Set oExec = testShell.exec("%comspec% /C CD C:\ & Dir")
>> WScript.Echo oExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
>>
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 ...
 25.05.2011  19:32    <DIR>          apache-ant-1.8.2
 ...
```

Comment: What does /C do? Trying it out now.

Comment: @tarrasch - [`cmd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx) creates a new command interpreter. `/k` keeps it open after the command is run. `/c` closes it after the command is run.